# JavaScript and WordPress: button click not found by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, wordpress

To prevent answers like: 'is the JavaScript file loaded?' -> Yes, it is loaded, at the footer part of the page! I have checked that with a simple message to the console, which is displayed!

But:

I've got a page with a button:

```
<button id="portfolio-posts-btn">Load portfolio related blog posts</button>
```

And a file main.js:

```
var portfolioPostsBtn = document.getElementById('portfolio-posts-btn');
var portfolioPostsContainer = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container");

if (portfolioPostsBtn) {
  portfolioPostsBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("the button was clicked!");
  });
}
```

The text `the button was clicked!` should be displayed in the console, but it stays empty!
Apparently, the button click is not recognized, and thus, the var portfolioPostsBtn is false, or NULL... -> the method `addEventListener()` is not fired ?

I don't see the cause for this; I checked the spelling, should I use single or double quotes? Please help?

Thank you!

Comment: It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/g9da081h/

Comment: Be sure that your javascript code is called after the DOM is initialized. Maybe in your case, the HTML doesn't exist yet when you call your script. I see no other reason, your code should work. Try typing in the chrome/firefox console `document.getElementById('portfolio-posts-btn')`. If it returns something, you got your problems. If it returns nothing, you just misspelled the id

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: `document.getElementById('portfolio-posts-btn')` in the console returns `null`.

Comment: Issue solved! See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found in the uploading of the file `page-portfolio.php`!

I found out that the `id="portfolio-posts-btn"`, added later, was not updated - could be my mistake, or the SFTP upload extension in Brackets - I did not see an error message!

Anyway, the issue is solved!

One more question: "are there methods to check if an `id` exists?". That could make live easier!

All contributors, thank you for your answers!

Comment: `document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-btn")` will have a `null` value if the element with `id="portfolio-posts-btn"` doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Dan!
And I can check it, of course:
`if (portfolioPostsBtn) { `
  `... code `
`} else {`
  `alert("element not found");`

or something simular.

Thank you,
Ad

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen to me before, since theres two ways to do this I just used the other.

The first is `onclick="function()"`, this is used as an attribute inside the element. Ex:

```js
function clicked(){
  alert("button clicked");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clicked();">Press me</button>
```

exaplaination: When you add this attribute to this element and I do believe some others when the button is clicked the specified code inside the quotes of the attibute will run. It doesn't have to be a number, e.g. `onclick="alert(12+4/2);"`. But this is more of HTML than JavaScript using this version

The other way is using what you've got which (to me) is a lot more difficult then it needs to be. Heres my example

```js
var b = document.getElementById("btn");

b.addEventListener("click", blogged);

function blogged(){
  alert("this post has been blogged");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Blog it</button>
```

This side of things has more to do with JavaScript and Event listeners. But the problem with you're code is that you're putting the event listener after you call the if statement. Here's my solution

```js
var portfolioPostsBtn = document.getElementById('portfolio-posts-btn');

portfolioPostsBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  check();
});

function check(){
  if(portfolioPostsBtn){
    console.log("posted");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="portfolio-posts-btn">press this to post<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have made a decision not to use jQuery. You'll need to wrap your code in an event listener so that the code is executed when the DOM is ready.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var portfolioPostsBtn = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-btn");
  var portfolioPostsContainer = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container");
  if (portfolioPostsBtn) {
    portfolioPostsBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log("the button was clicked!");
    });
  }
});
```